# (PHP) trying to detect google recaptcha code failure

Tags: php

So I am almost done creating this anti spam google recaptcha v3 form.
I get failure to the end.
could you see what is the problem?
I dont use this to send data to DB but to my email.
let me know if this is the problem, but i think not.
I am almost finished, here what I have done so far:

### (still getting Failed to save data. error)

```
 <?php


if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
//   print_r($_POST);
$url = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify";
$data = [  
'secret' => "censord",
'response' => $_POST['token'],
'remoteip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
];
$options = array(
  'http' => array(
     'header'  => "Content-type: application/
     x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
     'method' => 'POST',
     'content' => http_build_query($data)

  )

);

$context = stream_context_create($options);
$response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);


$res = json_decode($response, true);
if($res['success'] == true) {
    //save data to database
    echo '<div class="alert alert-success">
    <strong>Success!</strong> Data is saved.
    </div>';
} else {
    echo '<div class="alert alert-warning">
    <strong>warning!</strong> Failed to save data.
    </div>';
}

}
?>
```

------------------- and the form-----------

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $name = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes(trim($_POST['username'])));
    $email = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes(trim($_POST['email'])));
    $text = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes(trim($_POST['textt'])));
    if(!preg_match("/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/", $name)){
      $name_error = 'Invalid name';
    }

    if(!preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/", $email)){
      $email_error = 'Invalid email';
    }
    if(strlen($text) === 0){
      $message_error = 'Your message should not be empty';
    }
    if(preg_match('/http|www/i',$comments)) {
    $error_message .= "We do not allow a url in the comment.<br />";
  }
  }
?>

  <div id="container">
    <div class="form-wrap">
         <h1>Report bug</h1>
        <p>It's free and you help us make the programming wikipedia better!</p>

        <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="POST">

            <div class="form-group">

                <label for="username">Name:</label>
                <input type="text" name="username">
   <p><?php if(isset($name_error)) echo $name_error; ?></p>

            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Email:</label>
                <input type="email" name="email">
                  <p><?php if(isset($email_error)) echo $email_error; ?></p>

            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="textx">Message:</label>
                <textarea type="text" name="textt" rows="22" cols="42"></textarea>
   <p><?php if(isset($message_error)) echo $message_error; ?></p>



                <button type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn">Report us</button>

 <?php 
    if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !isset($name_error) && !isset($subject_error) && !isset($email_error) && !isset($message_error)){
      $to = 'censord'; // edit here
      $body = " Name: $name\n E-mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";
      if(mail($to, $subject, $body)){
        echo '<p style="color: green">Message sent</p>';
      }else{
        echo '<p>Error occurred, please try again later</p>';
      }
    }
  ?>
  <input type="hidden" id="token" name="token">
        </form>
      </div>

    </div>

  </body>
  <script>
grecaptcha.ready(function() {
    grecaptcha.execute('censord', {action: 'homepage'}).then(function(token) {
       console.log(token);
       document.getElementById("token").value = token;
    });
});
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Dude, I ran into this exact same problem the other day, and my solution/hack was to literally just include the parameters right into the url, like `$url = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=censord&response=$_POST[token]&remoteip=$_SERVER[REMOTE_ADDR]"`. I only tried this out of sheer desperation, so I have no idea why it worked, but after creating the context with the options array exactly as you have it, the request worked. Hopefully someone can give you an actual answer, because I want to know too.

Comment: i dont understand what fixed it for u